# How to efficiently subtract each row from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), 
columns=list('ABCD'))

dfs = []

for index in range(len(df)):
    subtracted = df - df.loc[index]
    dfs.append(subtracted)
```

Is there a way to do this with apply perhaps? Doing it like above gets pretty slow for large dataframes...

Comment: what do you want to get - `dfs` or `subtracted`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

Sample DF:

```
In [124]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

to get `dfs`:

```
In [126]: (df.values - df.values[:, None])
Out[126]:
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  3,  3],
        [ 6,  6,  6]],

       [[-3, -3, -3],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  3,  3]],

       [[-6, -6, -6],
        [-3, -3, -3],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```

to get `subtracted`:

```
In [127]: (df.values - df.values[:, None])[-1]
Out[127]:
array([[-6, -6, -6],
       [-3, -3, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

Some explanation:

```
df.values[:, None]
```

is a synonym for [df.values[:, np.newaxis]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
In [132]: df.values[:, np.newaxis]
Out[132]:
array([[[0, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 5]],

       [[6, 7, 8]]])
```

Comment: and maybe multiindex should be nice, if OP need DataFrame as output.

Comment: wow, when i time my way it comes out to ~1.3 ms, with your way its 13 us, 100x faster... could you please elaborate a bit on what you are doing here?
(df.values - df.values[:, None])

Comment: Really nice solution sir. Vectorization if really a vast topic. So much to learn